# eledpar apparatus footnote on the wrong page

Tags: footnotes, parallel, eledmac, eledpar

I'm typesetting some longer documents with facing pages using `eledmac` and `eledpar`.

Even if the documents compile with only few warnings, in some cases the footnotes of an apparatus of the last even numbered page do not appear on the same page but on a seperate attached page, that is left blank apart from that.

A minimal example with the same code compiles perfectly and I'm helpless, finding the reason for this behavior.

Any help would be gratefully welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have seen the file, and so, where was the problem.

@mxordn added some lines which look like:

```
\edtext{xxx}{}
```

And so, these lines created edtext without notes, which made eledmac/eledpar be troubled and write the critical notes in a bad place.

After correction, all is ok.

The next version of eledmac (still in development, but which will be published Friday on CTAN will send an error message in such case).

Answer (score 2):

That is a problem with eledpar. There is, actually, no general solution.

I am working, since one year, on a global solution, but for now it is not stable.

The only way you could try is to reduce \goalfraction, for example to 0.8

\renewcommand{\goalfraction}{0.8}

Read the hanbdbook about goalfraction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt help! I'll try out the \goalfraction command.

Comment: an other way is to "play" with apparatus size, with \maxhXnotes (read the handbook for further details).

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion. If tried out both possibilities, but unfortunatly none of them fully solved the problem. Am I using the \goalfraction command right, when I'm setting the \renewcommand*{\goalfraction}{xx} in the paragraph where it should take effect? In general the command only had an visible effect, when I put it in the preamble.

Comment: now, you should use it in preamble, and in any case, not in the notes.

Comment: could you send a screenshot?

Comment: I extracted the section where the problem occurs (about 4 pages 2x2). But in a this case all works and compiles fine. It seems to me that the problem is the result of the large documenta and my guess is that TeX carries some earlier difficulties with it and applies them (without any need) to the last page. Is there a possibility to get rid of old ballast for example with the \ledpb command?

Comment: As I said, the problem is know. It's link to the way eledpar manage the // ing. Please send my your full example by email. I will look at it.

Comment: Just sent you the files. Thank you in advance for your kind offer!

Comment: read my email. If ok, I will post a detailled answer here.